# XAML color labl background if text is empty

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to get a label in a syncfusion datatemplate to change the background colour to Green if the property value is null or empty.
It currently does not alter the background colour.
What do I need to do to make it work?

The project is using Xamarin with sync fusion controls on an Android app.

#### XAML

```
<Grid>
....
<Label Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}"  ... >
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                     Binding="{Binding Path=MyStringProperty,TargetNullValue=''}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
</Grid>
```

#### C# ViewModel

```
public nullable<int> myInteger {get;set;}
public string MyStringProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (myInteger=null || myInteger.Value < 1)
            return string.Empty;
        return myInteger?.ToString("n0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the syntax of the code you provided. Try to show something in the label. You will see that there are some syntax mistakes and you are using the wrong properties. If you are using an IDE it should tell you this. To get you started : the `Text` property doesn't exist on `Label` but it has a `Content` property

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}"  ... >
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference label}, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference label}, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

The first datatrigger is used when the text value is null and the second datatrigger is used when the text value is empty.

**Update:**

The datatrigger doesn't work for the null value but works for the empty value.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above to work in my code, I think because the Xamarin label is not processing the trigger for an empty or null label.

The solution I came up with is to handle the `BindingContextChanged` event.

##### XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}" BindingContextChanged="Handle_BindingContextChanged" />
```

##### Code behind

```
private void Handle_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label control= (Label)sender;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
        {
            control.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            control.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for I have a mistake for the TargetType in my code and I have edited it. In addition, the BindingContextChanged will not called every time when the value changed.